# Remove Wordpress Plugin functionality from admin side

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a WordPress plugin https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-postratings.
It also showing ratings on admin, when i visit http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php.
[image]
How do i remove those ratings from admin side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function in your functions.php file with the [manage_posts_columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_columns/) filter. I'm assuming your custom post type id 'tools' and the column is referenced by 'ratings'. If they are different you can just change that in the code.

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'custom_post_columns', 10, 2 );
function custom_post_columns( $columns, $post_type ) {

  switch ( $post_type ) {    

    //assuming the id for the custom post type is 'tools'
    case 'tools':
    unset(
      //I'm using 'ratings' but you'll have to check and see what the name for the column really is.
      $columns['ratings']
    );
    break;

  }

  return $columns;
}
```